# Saving login information with an npm global CLI package

Tags: node.js, npm

I've created an NPM CLI package which requires login for several actions, similar to npm which needs you to login for npm publish.

How do I save the login credentials?

Scenario:

- npm install -g myPackage
- myPackage login
- myPackage publish [args]

**More information:** The backend is a NodeJS Express server which uses Firebase for authentication. I will be using HTTP requests (POST) to login. Only login is required, the user will be created via a web page pre-hand by the user.

Comment: I think this may be too broad.  There's a lot of ways to do this, one that comes to mind is creating a temp file with a cookie or web token.  Read that file every time you start your program and act accordingly.

Comment: Digging into firebase CLI i've noticed they use: https://github.com/yeoman/configstore